# Issue in javascript for checking files extension

Tags: javascript

I  have written javascript for checking files extensions

```
 function Validate() {
    try {
        var Name = document.getElementById('<%=fiFile.ClientID %>').value;
        if (Name == "") {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            var index = Name.lastIndexOf('\\') + 1;
            var FileName = Name.substring(index, Name.length);


            var ext = extension(FileName)

            switch (ext) {
                case 'jpg':
                case 'gif':
                case 'png':
                case 'bmp':
                case 'pdf':
                case 'txt':
                case 'doc':
                case 'docx':
                case 'xls':
                case 'xlsx':
                case 'xlr':
                case 'mdf':
                case 'ppt':
                case 'pptx':
                case 'msg':
                case 'log':
                case 'bak':
                case 'xml':
                case 'html':
                case 'mp3':
                case 'm4a':
                case 'm3u':
                case 'mid':
                case 'wma':
                case 'wav':
                case 'mp4':
                case 'mpg':
                case 'm4v':
                case 'vob':
                case 'mnv':
                case 'rm':
                case 'mov':
                case 'flv':
                case 'wmv':
                        return true;
                    break;
                default:
                    alert('Select a proper file');
                    return false;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (err) {
        alert(FileName);
    }
}

function extension(fname) {
    try {
        var pos = fname.lastIndexOf(".");
        var strlen = fname.length;
        if (pos != -1 && strlen != pos + 1) {
            var ext = fname.split(".");
            var len = ext.length;
            var extension = ext[len - 1].toLowerCase();
        } else {
            extension = "No extension found";
        }
    }
    catch (errr)
    { }
    return extension;
}
```

When I upload other files like .exe, the page is still refreshed and files get saved. I want that when user will upload files with some other extensions the page should not get refreshed and files should not be saved. Please help me!!!

Comment: why don't you use standard javascript validation tools like jQuery validate or Angular?

Comment: can you please show me any inspiration for this?

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use HTML5 way for file select?

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*, video/*, audio/* application/msword, application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.ms-powerpoint">
```

You can always add the MIME type which I've missed or tweak at your will, but this file will restrict the file type to support and hence you don't have to make an explicit check for it.

Comment: I hope so. It's easiest way if the browser supports HTML5 or any pollyfill is being used, like Modernizr

Answer (score 1):

Solution with usage of jQuery libraries (`jquery.validate.min.js` and `additional-methods.js`):

```
$("#vform").validate({
    rules: {
        fileName: {
            extension: "jpg|gif|png|bmp|pdf|txt|doc|docx|xls|xlsx|xlr|mdf|ppt|pptx|msg|log|bak|xml|html|mp3|m4a|m3u|mid|wma|wav|mp4|mpg|m4v|vob|mnv|rm|mov|flv|wmv"
        }
    },
    messages: {
        fileName: "You may not upload this type of file."
    }
});
```

[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ivangrs/7fLpoLct/)

Answer (score 0):

you can use accept attribute for file input fields like below,

```
<form action="demo_form.asp">
<input type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Syntax:
`<input accept="file_extension|audio/*|video/*|image/*|media_type">`

file_extension--    A file extension starting with the STOP character, e.g: .gif, .jpg, .png, .doc
audio/* --  All sound files are accepted
video/* -- All video files are accepted
image/* -- All image files are accepted
media_type --   A valid media type, with no parameters. [Look at IANA Media Types](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml) for a complete list of standard media types

otherwise you can manually check like below,

```
<form action="demo_form.asp" onsubmit='return validate()' method="post">
<input type="file" name="pic">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

if your validate function give True as return then only form will submit otherwise do nothing.